# Should you based your best answer selection off of completeness or submission time?

Tags: discussion

When selecting the best answer to a question where multiple correct answers were given, should the best answer be selected solely by thoroughness; or should the time of submission also be a factor? To clarify my point, here is an example:

Say Bob asks a question at 6:30. Then Sally responds with the correct answer at 6:35. Then at 6:45, Joe responds with a similarly correct answer; however, Joe's response was more thorough even though they both answered the crux of the problem.

Should Sally be rewarded for her timely response, or should Joe be rewarded for his thoughtfulness?

EDIT: This example relies on the assumption that any response more thorough than Sally's would only contain tangential or complementary information that is not required to be understood to solve the original question.

Comment: The only time I consider the order of answers is when two answers are virtually the same; otherwise, the greenie goes to the "best" answer. If two answers represent two approaches to solving the problem, but are equally good, I still would not consider timeliness when choosing between them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can feel free to mark any answer as the accepted answer, it is entirely at your own discretion.

That said, I would recommend accepting the more complete answer, if for no other reason than, it encourages users to write complete answers rather than being the [fastest gun in the west](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem).

Comment: Although... This is the first correct answer so you should totally drop that and accept this answer.

Comment: lol - shameless self-promotion

Answer (score 0):

Choose the answer that not only best answers the question for you, but for whomever may be trying to resolve the same issue in future. That's the point of StackOverflow, to be a repository of useful knowledge, not just to solve your issue :)