# Should I accept the answer in this occassion

Tags: discussion

I asked a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24446578/differences-between-cast-arraylist-and-cast-array-in-java) for not searching the net thoroughly and being unfamiliar about some terms. Now I thought the answer [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666710/why-are-arrays-covariant-but-generics-are-invariant) is better, what should I do now?

**Related:** [What answer should I accept: faster vs more documented?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262284/what-answer-should-i-accept-faster-vs-more-documented/262285#262285)

Comment: accept&upvote the answer that helped you the most.

Comment: Just upvote the answer in the other post and accept the best answer on your post.

Answer (score 2):

The green check mark is a beacon to others, all it says is:

> This answer was the most suitable to the person that asked the question.

That could be for a variety of reasons:

- It taught you the most
- It went into your existing code the easiest, minimizing impact
- Through testing you found it to be the most optimal
- You like turtles

Accepted answers are *not* always indicative of the best, most technically sound, most optimal answer. It's just the mark that says "this worked the best for me", even if it scores only *half* as well as other answers, or sometimes even scores negatively. I've seen *plenty* of negatively-scored accepted answers and you know what? I kinda like those, because they show me pitfalls that are easy to fall into and why they're bad.

Don't worry about it. Accept the one that helped you the most, was the easiest to implement, or smells the most like a dandelion. Folks can see the relative scores, comments, etc and make their own informed decisions should they happen upon your question looking for something similar.

Comment: But I think the answer in another post is more helpful for me..So it is hard to decide.